# How to put some text (variables) in Cv::Mat image

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to put some variables in a video, and I use a `cv::mat` to take every frame of the camera. How can I put some text in this Matrix?

Comment: Please try to explain better what you want to do. By Matrix you mean the image right? In this case you want to draw text?

Comment: i Just need to add a sensor variable into my oculus rift rendering, and with mat i mean a matrix!

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV comes with some functionality for rendering text, mainly `cv::putText`. There is a good example in the [OpenCV reference](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#gettextsize).

Since you're going to put the same text in multiple frames (I'm assuming), I would render the text in a separate matrix that is later merged with the video frame matrices when your about to output the frames.

Comment: Do you think that'd offer a significant advantage? Is text rendering that slow compared to reallocating a channel?

Comment: Text rendering is slow, but it's a fair point - I'm making assumptions. I'm not sure if I follow with "reallocating a channel", though. I'm assuming that OP wants the text blended into the frames. Lots of assumptions, but there's not much to go on in the question.

Comment: I might've misunderstood - what did you mean by "merging with the video frame matrices"?